# How to create collections of records iteratively and render all at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have many arrays of values being sent from my view to the controller. Example:

```
year: ['2015','2016','2017']
cash: ['...','...','...']
.
.
.
```

0th index of each of these array forms one record in cashflow database table. 1st record another, and so on...cashflow is a collection inside "Property" model. I need to create these 'cashflows' iteratively whenever a record for 'property' is created.

I'm using sails framework. I am not able to create these records iteratively and render it all at once. I'm not sure if this needs to be done using async tasks.

```
Property.create(reqParams).exec(function(err, property) {
  if (err) {
    ...
  } else {
    var index = 0;
    var asyncTasks = [];

    for (index = 0; index < reqParams.year.length; index++) {

      asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {

          CashFlowProjections.create({
              year: reqParams.year[index],
              belongsTo: property.id,
              cash: reqParams.cash[index],
              ...)
            .exec(function(err, cashflows) {
              callback(err, cashflows);
            });
          });
      }

      async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          res.handleError(0, err);
        } else {
          res.view('property/preview', {
            cashflows: results[0],
            ...
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But the above code is wrong since the 'index' ends up being the same value for all the records and record creation fails.

I have also tried it without async tasks but I faced a problem of "res.view" getting executed before the creation of the cashflows records. Can someone guide me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of the variable `index`. `index` is scoped to the function that begins on line 1. `asyncTasks` becomes an array of functions which are *closures* - they share the variable with their enclosing scope. Since these functions are called asynchronously, after the `for` loop has finished, `index` has a value of `reqParams.year.length` by the time they are called.

To get round this, you could create a separate scope for each function, and in these scopes make a copy of `index`, which will not be affected by the `index++` of the original `index`. Like this:

```
for (index = 0; index < reqParams.year.length; index++) {

  (function(index) {
    asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {

      CashFlowProjections.create({
          year: reqParams.year[index],
          belongsTo: property.id,
          cash: reqParams.cash[index],
          ...})
        .exec(function(err, cashflows) {
          callback(err, cashflows);
      });
    });
  })(index);
}
```

If you do this, there are really two separate variables called `index`:

- the original one, declared on line 5 of your original script and used on the `for` line and also in `})(index);`. Its value starts as 0 and is incremented each time it goes through the loop.
- a new, inner one, declared at `function(index)`. This overrides the original one, but only inside the function definition. In fact this is really several separate scopes: every time it goes through the loop, it creates a new (anonymous) function and calls it, and calling the function creates the scope. Its value is set to whatever the outer `index` was at the time the loop was run, is never changed after that, and is used when `async.parallel` runs the task.

So if you prefer you can rename one of the two variables to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, @David. It worked!! I just found out this has been discussed on other post. Couldn't find it earlier since this post topic names the solution instead of the problem. :) Posting link here if it helps others like me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example